# How to check the header files required while using a PCL function？

Tags: point-cloud-library

[PCL API Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlATn.png)
Here is the PCL API Documentation, for example, which header files are required while using the function pcl::io::loadPolygonFile？

Answer (score 1):

Wellcome to Stack Overflow!

Well, if the documentation does not list the required header, I would definitely turn to the source code and using [grep](https://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) :)

---

As for your concrete example, I would:

- First, change into the directory where pcl source code stays, for my computer it's:
  `cd ~/library/pcl-pcl-1.9.1/`.
- Then, go to the directory where the header of the ***io*** module resides, that would be:
  `cd io/include/pcl/io/`
- Last, `grep -ir "loadpolygonfile"`

And it turns out the header should be `vtk_lib_io.h` :)
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jing Zhao's answer, which is basically searching through the code, you can also use Github advanced search as shown in the picture below.
[image]

If you're too lazy, you can also change the query `q=loadPolygonFile` in the link below to anything else
https://github.com/search?q=loadPolygonFile+repo%3APointCloudLibrary%2Fpcl+extension%3Ah+extension%3Ahpp&type=Code&ref=advsearch